# Calling Azure Migrate Rest Api Using Azure SDK for Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http-post, azure-sdk

I am trying to Make PUT request to craete project in azure migrate with spring boot .Previously i was doing with Rest Template. Like
@Autowire
RestTemplate template;

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

```
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("grant_type", assessment.getGrant_type());
    map.add("client_id", assessment.getClient_id());
    map.add("client_secret", assessment.getClient_secret());
    map.add("code", authToken);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

authToken i am getting making separate GET call to Authentication URL previous to POST call and setting in POST header.

I am posting partial code so that you can get an idea what i am doing.

Now i have been asked to use Azure-sdk for java to write the same code. I need not to use Rest Template.Can anybody tell me how can i make POST call using Azure-sdk for java classes.I search on google and you tube but nothing concrete found.

Regards,
Prabhash Mishra

Comment: Can any one give sample code as it is vary urgent.

Comment: Did you succeed in using Rest API with Azure Migrate service ? If so can you please upload sample code in answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Azure java sdk to call Azure rest API, please refer to the following code

a. create a service principal  (I use Azure CLI to do that)

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# the sp will have Azure Contributor role
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "readMetric"
```

[image]

2. Install sdk

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
    <version>1.33.0</version>
</dependency>
```

3. Code

```
 private static String tenantId="hanxia.onmicrosoft.com"; // sp tenant
    private static String clientId = "42e0d080-b1f3-40cf-8db6-c4c522d988c4"; // sp appid

    private static String clientKey = "Gbx*************JDfQpIjoae:";// sp password
    private static String subscriptionId="e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68"; //sp subscription id

ApplicationTokenCredentials creds = new
                ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId,tenantId,clientKey, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

        RestClient restClient =new RestClient.Builder()
                .withBaseUrl(AzureEnvironment.AZURE, AzureEnvironment.Endpoint.RESOURCE_MANAGER)
                .withSerializerAdapter(new AzureJacksonAdapter())
                .withReadTimeout(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BODY)
                .withResponseBuilderFactory(new AzureResponseBuilder.Factory())
                .withCredentials(creds)
                .build();
        OkHttpClient httpClient = restClient.httpClient().newBuilder().build();
        String url="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/"+subscriptionId+"/providers/Microsoft.Migrate/projects?api-version=2018-02-02";
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                              .url(url)
                              .method("get",null)
                              .build();
        Response response1 = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        if(response1.isSuccessful()){

            System.out.println(response1.headers().toString());

        }
```

[image]

Comment: I am Using Rate Card URL:final String getUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/"+assessment.getSubscriptionId()+"/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version="+assessment.getApi_version()+"&$filter=OfferDurableId eq '"+assessment.getOfferDurableId()+"' and Currency eq '"+ assessment.getCurrency()+ "' and Locale eq '"+ assessment.getLocale()+"' and RegionInfo eq '"+ assessment.getRegionInfo()+"'";                                                                                         With RestTemplate I am Getting the Output with this URL.But With Azure SDK code getting error.

Comment: ERROR:404 Not Found https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/0cc227d5-e23d-4f8f-818d-08c248d4f689/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId%20eq%20%27MS-AZR-0121p%27%20and%20Currency%20eq%20%27USD%27%20and%20Locale%20eq%20%27en-US%27%20and%20RegionInfo%20eq%20%27US%20%27 (138 ms, 0-byte body)
: 0-byte body:                                                                                                                       404 error means wrong URL.Can you please let me know where i am making mistake.   Thanks..

Comment: Can you please help me out in this issue.

Comment: @PrabhashMishra I made a mistake. Please update the request as `Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).get().build();` : https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2MOo.png